# When I click on the layout it spawn cylinder

Tags: modeling

I have problem with the fact that when I click somewhere on layout (it's the same with the other surfaces) with the cursor it spawn a cylinder. A cylinder spawns on the green spot when I click on the red space. How to fix it??

Sorry for English.

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please show a screenshot?

Comment: I don't know how screenshot could help, but there. When I click on the area with mouse the cylinder appears in the middle of the screen. (I clicked twice so there are two cylinders)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue is not clearly explained.

Comment: A cylinder spawns on the green spot when I click on the red space (picture)

Comment: that's all I know about the problem

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have accidentally assigned a shortcut to `add cylinder` command.

Use the `Add` menu, then `Mesh`, right click on `Cylinder` and use `Remove Shortcut`.

[image]

Comment: you're great thank you so much 

Comment: Hi, @James, could you give this answer a tick, so we can mark it as solved? Thanks.

Comment: I've tried every way I can think of to reproduce this:  https://imgur.com/a/nioGNEA , but I can't ...

Comment: Hi @RobinBetts, once the shortcut is set, you have to move your mouse to this zone to have it updated.